# comparing SQL select statement to user-entered value

Tags: java, sql

I have the following bit of code and I want to make sure that the user_entered_student_id is equal to an existing user_id.  How could I compare all user_id's to user_entered_student_id through a SQL statement?

```
System.out.println("\nSign Up For a Class\n");
try {

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ClassSelector?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "Volks91!");

    System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");
    user_entered_student_id = sc.nextLine();
    String selectClassId = "SELECT class_id FROM ClassSelector.classes";
    myStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectClassId);
    rs = myStmt.executeQuery(selectClassId);
    while (rs.next()) {

        if (selectClassId.equals(user_entered_student_id)) {
            System.out.println("This is not a valid User ID");
        }

        else {
            String selectStudentFromIdQuery = ("SELECT student_name FROM ClassSelector.students WHERE student_id = " + user_entered_student_id);
            myStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStudentFromIdQuery);
            rs = myStmt.executeQuery(selectStudentFromIdQuery);
            while (rs.next()) {
                userEnterIdAsName = rs.getString("student_name");
                System.out.println("Is " + userEnterIdAsName + " the correct student? (Y/N)");
                String confirm = sc.nextLine();

                if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    addClass();

                } else if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    System.out.println("Oops, let start over");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch ( java.sql.SQLException SQL ) {
    SQL.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: you already are doing that in the query itself? and note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: currently if the user enters an id that doesn't exist the app closes. I want a message saying the user_entered_student_id is not an actual student.

Comment: I reformatted the code, but it's still not quite working.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you comparing `class_id` to `user_entered_student_id` in first if/then conditional?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the app closes is that in your else block the query returns nothing for non-existent students and so nothing is looped in the `while (rs.next())...`

Consider running a check first as a resultset's `next()` returns false if the data is empty. Notice also the use of SQL parameterization (protects from sql injection). Additionally, the resultset is made scrollable to return to first when ready to loop for existing students after check:

```
String selectStudentFromIdQuery = ("SELECT student_name FROM ClassSelector.students " +
                                   "WHERE student_id = ?");

myStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStudentFromIdQuery,
                              ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
myStmt.setInt(1, user_entered_student_id);
rs = myStmt.executeQuery();

if (!rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("Not an actual student");
}
rs.beforeFirst();
while (rs.next()){    
    userEnterIdAsName = rs.getString("student_name");
    ...
}
```